# change timezone in ORACLE autonomous database

Tags: oracle, timezone, oracle-apex, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-autonomous-db

I want to use oracle cloud autonomous database but not able to see time in IST Timezone.

Is there any way to change timezone from UTC to IST at system level in oracle autonomous database in oracle cloud?

Or any workaround available for autonomous database for apex instance.

Thanks,
Yagnik

Comment: How are you looking at the time? `current_date` and `current_timestamp` will give you the date/time in you session time zone, rather than in the database server time zone (like `sysdate` and `systimestamp` do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "alter database set time_zone" command and restart the database to change the timezone. Note that if you are using sysdate and systimestamp, those will still return in UTC. You can use the sysdate_at_dbtimezone parameter to make them return in the database timezone you set.

See this doc, https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/autonomous-initialization-parameters.html#GUID-1D5E830F-2986-4E6C-AF8F-899AC3C85D07, for further information.

Comment: This document is quite useful for me and resolved the big hurlde.